# Crontab not working for pageres, showing error MTA installed, discarding output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

my ubuntu machine has pagers for taking screenshots, it is working when I run manually

```
root@bobby:~# pageres https://example.com 480x320 --format=jpg --filename 'page' --overwrite
```

But, when I enable cron entry it is not working and throwing MTA error, probably due to the output enabled.

```
* * * * * su bobby "/usr/bin/pageres https://example.com 480x320 --format=jpg --filename 'page' --overwrite" >> log.log

* * * * * su bobby "pageres https://example.com" >> log.log
```

both commands are not working.

Comment: Depending on **where** you create your cron entry as root you won't need to use `su` or `sudo` to run a command/script under a different UID, the **system crontab**  file format supports a sixt field requiring a user-name and which allows you to do that directly. - In addition to the duplicate link: a top reason cron jobs fail is that people don't use absolute path names to commands, files and directories